# can I call a select method from UIResponderStandardEditActions?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, select, uitextview

I'm currently developing a simple text editing app for iPad using UITextView.
I want to select parts of UITextView's text and highlight it with a default blue selection bar.

For example, I wrote this code to select the entire document.

```
[myTextView select: self]
myTextView.selectedRange = NSMakeRage(0, [textView.text length])
```

But "select" method is from UIResponderStandardEditActions protocol described as an informal protocol in the Apple documentation.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/UIResponderStandardEditActions.html

I wonder whether it's legal to call this method directly because most text editing apps based on UITextView in AppStore didn't have functionality to select parts of UITextView. So calling methods from UIResponderStandardEditActions seems illegal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is in the documentation, you can use it.