# Copy Text with Formatting - iOS 6 NSAttributedString to Pasteboard

Tags: ios, copy, ios6, nsattributedstring, uipasteboard

How can I programmatically copy formatted text (e.g. *italic*) from a UITextView, so that when pasted into another program (e.g. Mail) the formatting will be retained? I'm assuming the correct approach is to copy an NSAttributedString to the pasteboard. Right now, I am able to copy a regular string to the pasteboard via the following:

```
NSString *noteTitleAndBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", [document title], [document body]];
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
pasteboard.string = noteTitleAndBody;
```

I noticed that if I select and copy text from my UITextView with the standard text selection Copy menu item, it works as desired. But I need to access this via a button I've created.

I thought perhaps I could just call the [UIResponderStandardEditActions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/UIResponderStandardEditActions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008313-CH1-SW1) Copy method. Using the following, the paste into Mail did retain the formatting, but my app also crashed as a result.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *noteTitleAndBody = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[document title]];
[noteTitleAndBody appendAttributedString:[document body]];
[noteTitleAndBody copy:nil];
```

Examples of the correct way to do this would be greatly appreciated.

PS - I am aware that there are existing threads related to NSAttributedString and the pasteboard, but they seem to either be [for Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581407/copy-nsattributedstring-to-pasteboard), [don't reference the UIResponderStandardEditActions Copy method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601039/copy-nsattributedstring-in-uipasteboard), or predate iOS 6 where many of the UITextView attributes became available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work for whatever textView is currently first responder:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(copy:) to:nil from:self forEvent:nil];
```

Since my copy button is only accessible when my textView had resigned firstResponder, I had to do a little more:

```
[self.noteTextView select:self];
self.noteTextView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [self.noteTextView.text length]);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(copy:) to:nil from:self forEvent:nil];
[self.noteTextView resignFirstResponder];
```

Thanks to the following posts which pointed me in the right direction:

[Perform copy/cut from UIResponderStandardEditActions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031175/perform-copy-cut-from-uiresponderstandardeditactions)

[can I call a select method from UIResponderStandardEditActions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641087/can-i-call-a-select-method-from-uiresponderstandardeditactions)

Comment: You don't have to make the `UITextView` become `firstResponder`, you can just call `sendAction:@selector(copy:) to: self.noteTextView`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This works, as long as I continue to do the range selection for the view: self.noteTextView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [self.noteTextView.text length]);