# iOS: how to copy Text with font

Tags: ios, fonts, copy

it's a bit of tricky question but i hope some can help me

i want to have a label with custom font in my ios app and if i copied the text in it and paste it any where else .. in another app maybe .. that it pasted with the same font..

i know it's doable i found and app did it before .. but i have no idea how is that!

i used this code but it just copy a text from label

```
NSString *copyStringverse =     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.label.text];
UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pb setString:copyStringverse];
```

any idea?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789507/copy-text-with-formatting-ios-6-nsattributedstring-to-pasteboard

Comment: there is also an article about it here http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3397?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: @RachelGallen i used that lines 
 [self.noteTextView select:self];
    self.noteTextView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [self.noteTextView.text length]);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(copy:) to:nil from:self forEvent:nil];
    [self.noteTextView resignFirstResponder];
and i removed what i used above .. but nothing changed.. how should it work

Comment: @Mohammed Emad Hegab I'm at a loss then. thought that would work.

Comment: it should work i just don't know how :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `NSAttributedString` instead of `NSString`

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: ok it worked .. but if you can give me a hint about how to set this attributedString into  UIPasteboard

Comment: you cannot use 
[pb setString:attributedstring];
to set NSAttributedString here as it only accept NSString.

Instead try this

[pb setValue:attributedstring forKey:@"Mystring"];

This might work, give it a try.

Comment: well it gives me error 
[<UIPasteboard 0x10f04e60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key pb.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to set NSAttributedString in UIPasteboard because it accepts only few datatypes like
string,image,URL,Color.

So I would suggest you to use NSString and then use string and color setters of pasteboard
i.e.
[pb setString:myString];
[pb setColor:myStringColor];

But again there is no way to pass the size of string.

Comment: i don't want size i just want the fonts any way i'll try this and tell you